# How to set windows 10 title bar button style on all app windows with MahApps

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm new to WPF, and I am using MahApps. I want to set Windows 10 style titlebar buttons on all windows in my app. I can do this separately for each window by adding

```
<ma:MetroWindow.WindowButtonCommands>
    <ma:WindowButtonCommands Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.WindowButtonCommands.Win10}" />
</ma:MetroWindow.WindowButtonCommands>
```

to each window xaml. However, I would like to set this as a style in App.xaml so I don't have to duplicate this in every window. I tried

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ma:MetroWindow}">
            <Setter Property="WindowButtonCommands">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ma:WindowButtonCommands Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.WindowButtonCommands.Win10}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

but it only works for the first window. Subsequent windows opened crash with the error "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first." Apparently, only one instance of WindowButtonCommands is instantiated and can only be assigned to one window. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I had similar problem, I fixed it by creating base window which inherits from Window, then i base we add style to base window, so when we create new window , we inherit from base window. In that case your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the `WindowButtonCommands` element as a separate non-shared resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ma:WindowButtonCommands x:Key="commands" x:Shared="False" Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.WindowButtonCommands.Win10}" />
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ma:MetroWindow}">
            <Setter Property="WindowButtonCommands" Value="{StaticResource commands}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the shared attribute. I have actually changed my approach, so I can't test this, but I will mark it as the answer.